# T-SQL | Summarize grouped aggregates into a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tab1 (Tag1 varchar(5), Tag2 varchar(5), Tag3 varchar(5), InvalidFlag bit, JunkFlag bit, Old int, New int, Combined int)
INSERT INTO #Tab1
SELECT 'NK','DJ','Name1',0,0,5,2,7
UNION
SELECT 'NK','IJ','Name2',0,0,4,2,6
UNION
SELECT 'NK','KJ','Name3',0,0,4,1,5
UNION
SELECT 'NK','KJ','Name3',0,1,0,1,1
UNION
SELECT 'PK','EK','Name4',0,0,2,2,4
UNION ALl
SELECT 'PK','EK','Name4',1,0,1,0,1
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM #Tab1
```

Output

```
Tag1    Tag2    Tag3    InvalidFlag JunkFlag    Old New Combined
NK      DJ      Name1   0           0           5   2   7
NK      IJ      Name2   0           0           4   2   6
NK      KJ      Name3   0           0           4   1   5
NK      KJ      Name3   0           1           0   1   1
PK      EK      Name4   0           0           2   2   4
PK      EK      Name4   1           0           1   0   1
```

Desired output

```
Tag1    Tag2    Tag3    Old                                     New
NK      DJ      Name1   | Valid - 5 |Invalid - 0 | Junk - 0     | Valid - 2 |Invalid - 0 | Junk - 0
NK      IJ      Name2   | Valid - 4 |Invalid - 0 | Junk - 0     | Valid - 2 |Invalid - 0 | Junk - 0
NK      KJ      Name3   | Valid - 4 |Invalid - 0 | Junk - 1     | Valid - 1 |Invalid - 0 | Junk - 1
PK      EK      Name4   | Valid - 2 |Invalid - 1 | Junk - 0     | Valid - 2 |Invalid - 0 | Junk - 0
```

Goal

I want to group the records based on Tag1, Tag2, and Tag3 and aggregate Old and New records based on InvalidFlag and JunkFlag. i.e. for the first record, for Old field, If InvalidFlag = 0 and If JunkFlag = 0 Then Old (output) field = Valid - 5 | Invalid - 0 (since there is no other record for the same grouped Tag1, Tag2, and Tag3 records with InvalidFlag = 1) | Junk - 0 (since there is no other record for the same grouped Tag1, Tag2, and Tag3 records with RejectedFlag = 1)

My try so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
, '| Valid - ' + CASE WHEN InvalidFlag = 0 AND JunkFlag = 0 THEN ISNULL(CAST(SUM(Old) OVER(Partition by Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, InvalidFlag, JunkFlag) AS varchar(10)),'0') END
+ ' | Invalid - ' + CASE WHEN InvalidFlag = 1 THEN ISNULL(CAST(SUM(Old) OVER(Partition by Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, InvalidFlag, JunkFlag) AS varchar(10)),'0') END
+ ' | Junk - ' + CASE  WHEN JunkFlag = 1 THEN ISNULL(CAST(SUM(Old) OVER(Partition by Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, InvalidFlag, JunkFlag) AS varchar(10)),'0') END
AS Old
, '| Valid - ' + CASE WHEN InvalidFlag = 0 AND JunkFlag = 0 THEN ISNULL(CAST(SUM(New) OVER(Partition by Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, InvalidFlag, JunkFlag) AS varchar(10)),'0') END
+ ' | Invalid - ' + CASE WHEN InvalidFlag = 1 THEN ISNULL(CAST(SUM(New) OVER(Partition by Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, InvalidFlag, JunkFlag) AS varchar(10)),'0') END
+ ' | Junk - ' + CASE  WHEN JunkFlag = 1 THEN ISNULL(CAST(SUM(New) OVER(Partition by Tag1, Tag2, Tag3, InvalidFlag, JunkFlag) AS varchar(10)),'0') END
AS New
FROM #Tab1
GROUP BY Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
```

Comment: You need to use `group by Tag1, Tag2`. Then replace the analytics with regular aggregates that `sum()` the `case` expressions (outside) and you're probably close. I didn't have time to make a lot of sense of your logic though so apologies if I missed something else that's complicated.

Comment: oops, sorry, missed the FROM and GROUP BY clause when I copy/pasted it. But thanks for the clue and yea... sorry for the unclear "goal". Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this works, I'll leave it to you to combine the integers into text, I think the salient part is to use case and sum (it's called conditional aggregation) and it looks like this:

```
SELECT
    tag1
    ,tag2 
    ,tag3
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN invalidflag = 0 and junkFlag = 0 then old else 0 end) as oldvalid
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN invalidflag = 1 and junkFlag = 0 then old else 0 end) as oldvinvalid 
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN invalidflag = 0 and junkflag = 1 then old else 0 end) as oldjunk

    ,SUM(CASE WHEN invalidflag = 0 and junkFlag = 0 then new else 0 end) as newvalid
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN invalidflag = 1 and junkFlag = 0 then new else 0 end) as newinvalid 
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN invalidflag = 0 and junkflag = 1 then new else 0 end) as newjunk
FROM 
    #tab1
GROUP BY 
    tag1, tag2, tag3
```

Comment: This works, thanks! are you a mongoDB dev by any change? the first thing that came up when I searched by"Conditional Aggregation" was MongoDB. haha. anyways, thanks!

Comment: No sir!  I did take their 6 week online class (free) and learned a lot.  But no, I've been all Microsoft, all the time.  I'm trying to branch out.

Comment: not to go off topic but I also signed up for their free course for last month...  got busy and missed out on attending it. Going see if I can review the course material and learn on my own. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tough for me to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but using `SUM`, `MAX`, and `CONCAT` (to save some of the casting and null checking) seems to get pretty close:

```
SELECT Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
    ,CONCAT('| Valid - ', MAX(Old), ' | Invalid - ', SUM(Cast(InvalidFlag AS INT)), ' | Junk - ', SUM(Cast(JunkFlag AS INT))) as Old
    ,CONCAT('| Valid - ', MAX(New), ' | Invalid - ', SUM(Cast(InvalidFlag AS INT)), ' | Junk - ', SUM(Cast(JunkFlag AS INT))) as New
FROM #Tab1
GROUP BY Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan field for your input. sorry for the confusing "goal" This solution worked for the most part except the last aggregate (PK EK Name4 | Valid - 2 | Invalid - 1 | Junk - 0 | Valid - 2 | Invalid - 1 | Junk - 0) where it had one invalid for NEW (which should be Junk instead). Wonder what your logic is behind using MAX...

Comment: More meant to illustrate how you could use the aggregate functions - and it seemed to produce your desired output, though admittedly I wasn't 100% clear on what your expectations were